# how can i grab a text from a href in a website (page source) using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, href

This is the part of page source of a website. 
I need to grab the " crsEdId=78 " in the last line. Using JavaScript or JQuery.

I will use mozilla Jetpack to do the task.

How can i Get this Code first?
and What to do (RegEx or JQuery) on it  !?

```
<div class="tools-menu-body" id="tools-menu-div" style="display: none;">
        <div id="menu_glider">
            <div class="scroller">
                <div class="content">
                     <div class="section" id="courses_menu">
                        <ul class="tools-menu-ul">
                            <li class="tools-menu-back"><a href="#main_menu" class="controls">back</a></li>
<li><a title="Advanced Software Engineering Lab: Open Source Development" href="../Courses/CourseEdition.aspx?crsEdId=78">CSEN 914 </a></li>
```

IT WORKED :

well it was a stupid thing - i just had to put the selector inside the click function, donno why i didn't think about it earlier.

```
  jetpack.statusBar.append({
  html: "Boom<i>!</i>",
  width: 45,
  onReady: function(widget){
      $(widget).click(function(){
             var doc= jetpack.tabs.focused.contentDocument;
             var link= doc.querySelector('#courses_menu > ul > li:nth-child(2) a');
             var test= doc.getElementById('#container'); 
             jetpack.notifications.show("Course is is = "+ link);

});
}
});
```

Now i need to get all the href inside this courses_menu !! Can you help in that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
alert($('#courses_menu').children('li').get(2).attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just get the href for that element, then use RegEx to get what you want?

Comment: I am kinda new in JavaScript and RegEx , Can you show me how would this work !?
or link me to it !

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of what andybaird posted.  But you may need to be more specific in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
var matches = $('a').attr('href').match(/crsEdId=(\d+)/);
```

Comment: Jetpack outputs 

$("a").attr("href") is undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the document in the current tab, I believe Jetpack gives it to you like:

```
var doc= jetpack.tabs.focused.contentDocument;
```

Then in plain JS, get hold of the link by whatever means is most appropriate. For example to get the first link from the second list item:

```
var menu= doc.getElementById('courses_menu');
var link= menu.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

If you are using Jetpack you can presumably rely on a new enough version of Firefox to have native support for the Selectors-API, so you could get this more easily without the use of an additional library such as jQuery, eg.:

```
var link= doc.querySelector('#courses_menu>ul>li:nth-child(2) a');
```

Now old-school DOM Level 0 gives you several easy properties to get the parts of a URL inside a link without having to resort to unreliable regex processing. If you want the whole query string `crsEdId=78`, you can say:

```
var query= link.search.substring(1);
```

(the substring is to take off any leading `?` character.)

If there might be more query parameters and you want to specifically find the one called `crsEdId` you'd have to process the query fully, eg.:

```
var crsEdId= getParameter(query, 'crsEdId');

function getParameter(query, name) {
    var pars= query.split(/[&;]/g);
    for (var i= pars.length; i-->0;) {
        var n= pars[i].split('=')[0];
        if (decodeURIComponent(n)===name)
            return decodeURIComponent(pars[i].substring(n.length+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: it is Giving me null !! 

here is the website iam tryin to work on http://met.guc.edu.eg/

and thats the code iam trying to do      var doc= jetpack.tabs.focused.contentDocument;
var link= doc.querySelector('#courses_menu>ul>li>li:nth-child(2) a');

 jetpack.statusBar.append({
  html: "Boom<i>!</i>",
  width: 45,
  onReady: function(widget){
$(widget).click(function(){

 jetpack.notifications.show( " "+link+" " );
     
    });
  }
});

Comment: There seems to be a spurious extra `>li` in that selector.

Comment: yeah , i was just trying something - .. well with and without it , its still giving me null

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the null? Is `link` null? Can you get `#courses_menu` on its own? Which part is failing here?

Comment: The link is giving me null , iam printing the link ,  i will try to debug it , ( am kinda new in JS )

Comment: Post some example code? The selector certainly *should* match the HTML given above.

Comment: I updated the post , take a look. Thanks a lot for you time and effort :)

Comment: You're getting `main_menu`; there's no element with that id; you want `courses_menu`.

Comment: Still gives me null !! 
am readying the JQuery documentation now, maybe ill find something 

Thanks alot Bobince

Comment: Incidentally there's an additional problem with the `getElementById` call; you shouldn't include the selector-style `#` before the ID in this method. ie. should be `doc.getElementById('courses_menu');`.